# Consulta para obtener el producto más solicitado

Tags: sql, join, tablas

Debo obtener el producto que más se ha solicitado en la tabla detalles, pero no consigo que la consulta funcione.

```
SELECT codigo,nombre,descripcion,imagen,existencias,precio
FROM productos RIGHT JOIN detalle
ON productos.codigo=detalle.codigo_producto WHERE (SELECT... )  GROUP BY productos.codigo
ORDER BY productos.codigo DESC;
```

Y por solicitado me refiero a:

```
SELECT detalle.codigo_producto,count(detalle.codigo_producto)*detalle.unidades as sol FROM `detalle` GROUP BY detalle.codigo_producto ORDER BY sol DESC;
```

Tal que así:

[image: Resultado consulta]

que me devuelva el producto de la primera fila del resultado de esta consulta directamente.

Esta es mi BD:

```
--
-- Base de datos: `bd_tienda`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `detalle`
--

CREATE TABLE `detalle` (
  `codigo_pedido` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `codigo_producto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `unidades` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `precio_unitario` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `detalle`
--

INSERT INTO `detalle` (`codigo_pedido`, `codigo_producto`, `unidades`, `precio_unitario`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '35.00'),
(8, 2, 4, '35.00'),
(8, 3, 8, '35.00');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `pedidos`
--

CREATE TABLE `pedidos` (
  `codigo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_persona` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `importe` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `pedidos`
--

INSERT INTO `pedidos` (`codigo`, `id_persona`, `fecha`, `importe`, `estado`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2022-04-27', '35.00', 2),
(8, 1, '2022-05-08', '0.00', 2);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `productos`
--

CREATE TABLE `productos` (
  `codigo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `precio` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `existencias` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imagen` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `productos`
--

INSERT INTO `productos` (`codigo`, `nombre`, `descripcion`, `precio`, `existencias`, `imagen`) VALUES
(1, 'Cilindro Neumatico SCJ40', 'Cilindro Neumático SCJ40 con 60 NW de fuerza, con un consumo de 0,5 ml^3 de gas presurizado como actuador.Disponible en múltiples terminaciones.', '35.00', 5, '.\\img\\prods\\Cilindro-neumatico-SCJ40.jpg'),
(2, 'Motor Electrico Siemens D-91066', 'Motor Electrico Siemens D-91066 con una potencia de 66 HP.Con un consumo de 12 W/h disponible con cilindro interno pulido o áspero. ', '220.00', 5, '.\\img\\prods\\motor-electrico-Siemens-D-91066.jpg'),
(3, 'ENGRANAJE CILÍNDRICO RECTO', 'ENGRANAJE CILÍNDRICO RECTO MÓDULO 1 Z-24 de 24 mm de diámetro hecho de acero forjado a alta temperatura. Cargado con cabeza cilíndrica del tipo Módulo 1.', '2.00', 55, '.\\img\\prods\\ENGRANAJE_CILINDRICO_RECTO_MODULO_1_Z-24.jpg');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `usuarios`
--

CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `codigo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `activo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clave` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `domicilio` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `poblacion` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `provincia` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cp` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefono` char(9) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `usuarios`
--

INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`codigo`, `activo`, `admin`, `usuario`, `clave`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `domicilio`, `poblacion`, `provincia`, `cp`, `telefono`) VALUES
(1, 1, 0, 'alex', '1234', 'Alejandro', 'Mancebo Arnal', 'C/Dr.Marañon 3', 'Burjasot', 'Valencia', '46100', '963902972'),
(2, 1, 1, 'admin', '1234', 'Administrador', 'Admin', '---', '---', '---', '0000', '000000000'),
(5, 1, 0, 'aaa', 'aaa', 'Alejandro', 'dfgsdg', 'Mancebo', 'Burjasot', 'VALENCIA', '46100', '0'),
(6, 1, 0, 'alexvv', 'vv', 'vvxc', 'cxvxv', 'xcvxcv', 'cxvxcv', 'xvcxv', '46100', '555444777');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `detalle`
--
ALTER TABLE `detalle`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codigo_pedido`,`codigo_producto`),
  ADD KEY `contiene` (`codigo_producto`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `pedidos`
--
ALTER TABLE `pedidos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`),
  ADD KEY `pedidopor` (`id_persona`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `productos`
--
ALTER TABLE `productos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `usuarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `usuario` (`usuario`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `pedidos`
--
ALTER TABLE `pedidos`
  MODIFY `codigo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=9;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `productos`
--
ALTER TABLE `productos`
  MODIFY `codigo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `usuarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  MODIFY `codigo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `detalle`
--
ALTER TABLE `detalle`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `contiene` FOREIGN KEY (`codigo_producto`) REFERENCES `productos` (`codigo`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `referentea` FOREIGN KEY (`codigo_pedido`) REFERENCES `pedidos` (`codigo`);

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `pedidos`
--
ALTER TABLE `pedidos`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `pedidopor` FOREIGN KEY (`id_persona`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`codigo`);
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día, por lo que entendí quieres traer únicamente el producto mas solicitado (en pocas palabras solo 1 registro). Si es así, solo agrega "limit" a tu query y ordena por la cantidad de productos solicitado, te dejo el query que te puede servir:

```
    select codigo,nombre,descripcion,imagen,existencias,precio,max(sol) sol from ( SELECT codigo,nombre,descripcion,imagen,existencias,precio, sum(b.unidades) as sol FROM productos a INNER JOIN detalle b ON a.codigo=b.codigo_producto )a group by codigo,nombre,descripcion,imagen,existencias,precio order by sol desc Limit 1;
```

Recree tu BD en mi local, el error es la falta de una coma antes del "sum":
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La idea es esa pero me di cuenta que en vez de usar la operación de count()*unidades podría haber hecho un sum(unidades) , además no funciona el código.

Comment: Buen día, alejandro, edite la respuesta y te mande ejemplo de la ejecución, el error era por falta de una coma, fuera de eso el código funciona, de igual manera ya lo corregi.